# How to count all elements above my element in XML via XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to count all elements that stay above my element. For example, this is my XML:

```xml
<a>
  <b>
    <c/>
  </b>
  <d>
    <f/>
  </d>
  <e/>
</a>
```

If my element is `<f/>`, the result should be 4, since `<a>`, `<b>`, `<c>`, and `<d>` stay "above" it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XPath/XSLT data model has no concept of "above". It operates on the XML document as a *tree*.

In this tree, the `f` element is a **child** of `d` and a **descendant** of `a` -  and is preceded **only** by `b` and `c`. Thus if you add the number of ancestor and preceding elements:

```
count(//f/ancestor::*) + count(//f/preceding::*)
```

you will get 4 - but I am not sure if that's the logic you are interested in.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you could use `<xsl:number count="*" level="any"/>` and substract 1, as in e.g.

```
  <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:comment>
          <xsl:variable name="pos">
              <xsl:number count="*" level="any"/>
          </xsl:variable>
          <xsl:value-of select="$pos - 1"/>
      </xsl:comment>
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```